# What caching is enabled by default when using Express and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I seem to be having old extraneous results that are polluting database queries I make. What kind of caching is enabled for the stack Express.js > Mongoose.js? Is there a way to disable it or clear it?

Comment: Express doesn't have anything to do with Mongoose's queries :)

Comment: Sure. So it's two different questions. What does Express cache? What does Mongoose cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express has 'view cache' [enabled by default](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#settings) in 'production' mode.
Checkout the code for that here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L532-557

Other than that you might be using the [connect-static middleware](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html), which has browser cache.

As far as I know and from what I've looked at the Mongoosejs code, I didn't see any caching stuff there.